# Rails Engine - RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I my main rails project I have mounted a engine of common code which does common tasks like currency conversion.

I can reference the methods in this common engine like this:

```
MyCommon::CurrencyHelper.convert_to_currency
```

This works fine in the project code, but does not seem to be working when I change the RSpec tests to point to the common methods.

The tests fail as it cannot find the common methods:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `convert_to_currency' for MyCommon::CurrencyHelper:Module
./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:211:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

If by "I change the RSpec tests to point to the common methods" you mean that you are running the RSpec tests from engines/my_common directory (the engine's tests found in engines/my_common/spec) then you can find/reference your `convert_to_currency` method like this `CurrencyHelper.convert_to_currency` in your tests.

So for example, `Stuff::BookingSlot.book_a_slot!` (where `Stuff` is the engine) would be tested like this:

```
it 'book_a_slot! marks a slot as unavailable when a host is available' do
    ai = FactoryGirl.create(:booking_slot, available: false, host_id: 1)
    ai2 = ai.clone
    ai2.update_attributes(available: true, host_id: 2)
    BookingSlot.book_a_slot!
    expect(ai2.reload.available).to eq false
end
```